# Scala: using None for other purposes than empty Option

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scala-option

According to the docs, `None` object is intended to "represent non-existent values". As far as I've seen it's mostly used as an empty `Option`. But do you think it's a good idea to use it for other purposes. For example, in my library I want to have an universal "Empty" object which could be assigned for various missing values, where I would just implicitly convert the "Empty" value to my types as needed:

```
// In library:
trait A {
  implicit def noneToT1(none: Option[Nothing]): T1 = defaultT1
  implicit def noneToT2(none: Option[Nothing]): T2 = defaultT2
  def f1: T1
  def f2: T2
}
// In the code that uses the library
class EmptyA extends A {
  def f1 = None      
  def f2 = None      
}
```

One reason for not (mis)using `None` in this fashion is that the user would expect that `f1` and `f2` return `Option[T1]` and `Option[T2]` respectively. And they don't. Off course, I could have `def f1: Option[T1]`, but in this case the values are not actually optional, they just can have some default empty value, or a real value, I just want to create the default values "under the hood" and have some uniform way of saying "default" or "empty" through the entire library. So the question is, should I use `None` to express this "defaultness" or go for some custom type? Right now I'm using my own `object Empty`, but it feels a bit superfluous.

**EDIT:**
To ilustrate my question I'll add the code I am using right now:

```
// In library:
trait Empty
object Empty extends Empty

trait A {
  implicit def emptyToT1(none: Empty): T1 = defaultT1
  implicit def emptyToT2(none: Empty): T2 = defaultT2
  def f1: T1
  def f2: T2
}
// In the code that uses the library
class EmptyA extends A {
  def f1 = Empty
  def f2 = Empty
}
class HalfFullA extends A {
  def f1 = Empty
  def f2 = someValue2
}
class FullA extends A {
  def f1 = someValue1
  def f2 = someValue2
}
```

My question is quite simple: is it a good idea to use scala's `None` instead of my `Empty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't or don't want to define the default value using inheritance, I suggest to keep the new object. Reusing `None` for something else than the `Some` counterpart seems wrong and doesn't really save you much.

Answer (score 7):

I would just use typeclasses for this:

```
trait WithDefault[T] {
  def default: T
}

object WithDefault {
  // if T1 is an existing class
  implicit val t1Default = new WithDefault[T1] {def default = defaultT1}
}

//if T2 is your own class:
class T2 ...
object T2 {
  implicit val withDefault = new WithDefault[T2] {def default = defaultT2}
}
```

then somewhere convenient:

```
def default[T : WithDefault] = implicitly[WithDefault[T]].default
```

and use:

```
class EmptyA {
  def f1 = default[T1]
  def f2 = default[T2]
}
```

Update: To accomudate Vilius, one can try this:

```
def default = new WithDefault[Nothing]{def default = error("no default")}

implicit def toDefault[U, T](dummy: WithDefault[U])(implicit withDefault: WithDefault[T]): T = withDefault.default

class EmptyA {
  def f1: T1 = default
  def f2: T2 = default
}
```

This has the benefit over the OP's original attempt in that each new class can define its own default (and others in WithDefault), rather than have everything in a trait `A`.

However, this doesn't work. See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2046

To work around this:

```
trait A {
    def f1: T1
    def f2: T2

    implicit def toT1Default(dummy: WithDefault[Nothing]) = toDefault[T1](dummy)
    implicit def toT2Default(dummy: WithDefault[Nothing]) = toDefault[T2](dummy)
}

class EmptyA extends A {
   def f1 = default
   def f2 = default
}
```

Comment: It's a nice solution, I haven't thought of it. I like it because you have a uniform way of creating default values, but still do not confuse the user about the method's type. Yet in this particular library that would be a bit of an overkill, and would still look ugly - for example, some of my methods return partial functions, so I would have to write: `default[PartialFunction[SomeType, OtherType]]` (off course I could have type aliases, but that would be event more of an overkill)

Comment: Can't Scala deduce the type parameter in such a situation?

Comment: updated my answer. Scala can't deduce the type since if infers the expression type and from it the method's return type, not the other way round.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should go for something much simpler. For instance, starting with your example and deleting extraneous stuff we very quickly get to,

```
trait A {
  def noT1 = defaultT1
  def noT2 = defaultT2
  def f1: T1
  def f2: T2
}

class EmptyA extends A {
  def f1 = noT1      
  def f2 = noT2      
}
```

I really don't see that the addition of Options or implicits to this would add any value, at least not unless there's some other unstated context for the question.

Comment: The problem is, that I want to express `noT1` and `noT2` and probably many other `noXX` by one word which would be uniform through my library. In some case this can be an empty list or set, in other case a partial function which performs some default "empty" action, or something else. And I want to hide all those `Nil`, `Set.empty`, or `{ case _ => }` under some magic one-word expression. The question is, should I use `None` for this purpose or invent something else (which I do right now - I use `object Empty`)?